# Single quotes problem in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, quotes

How this below insert query can be modified or escape single quote in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO <tblname> (title,desc)
VALUES
('Hen's Body','It's just best combination')
```

This query not run in SQL Server. I need similer solution to MySQL (like using backslash)as it is

```
INSERT INTO <tblname> (title,desc)
VALUES('Hen\'s Body','It\'s just best combination')
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double up the single quotes to escape them:

```
INSERT INTO ( title, description ) 
VALUES ( 'Hen''s Body', 'It''s just best combination' )
```